# How to import a custom control DLL to a new project?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom control DLL in `Project1`. I want to use the custom control DLL in `Project2`. I added a reference of the DLL in `Project2` but I am not able to see it in my toolbox.

Comment: You have to add it to the toolbox.  Right-click it, Choose Items, Browse tab.  Or just make a solution with both projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items are not automatically added to the toolbox when they are added as a reference to the project.

The easiest way to add the items to the toolbox is to drag a copy of the DLL from windows explorer onto the toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

Open any form of Project2. Then:

1. Right-click
2. Choose Items...
3. Browse
4. Select your Project1.dll
5. Click OK

Then they should appear in your toolbox.